# Optional String Match in Python

Tags: python, regex, nlp

I want to make the last string optional here, following is my original code:

```
[0-9]{1,2}\.[0-9]{1,2}\.[0-9]{2,4}
```

Following is the code I tried (Getting Invalid Parantheses Error):

```
[0-9]{1,2}\.[0-9]{1,2}\(?:.[0-9]{2,4})?
```

Current Code is Capturing Following Utterance:

```
12.2.17
3.04.2018
```

I further want it to capture the following by making the last part optional:

```
12.2
13.03
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You seem to have accidentally escaped the `(` character instead of creating a non-capture group. Here's the new regex:

```
[0-9]{1,2}\.[0-9]{1,2}(?:.[0-9]{2,4})?
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also write your regex in a more compact way:

```
\d{1,2}\.\d{1,2}(\.\d{2,4})?
```

Answer (score 0):

As for your error:

```
[0-9]{1,2}\.[0-9]{1,2}\(?:.[0-9]{2,4})?
#                   --^--  no backslash here!
```

Alternatively, you could use

```
\d+\.\d+(?:\.\d+)?
```

See [**a demo on regex101.com**](https://regex101.com/r/qM0NsL/1).

---

In `Python`:

```
import re

string = """
12.2.17
3.04.2018

I further want it to capture the following by making the last part optional:

12.2
13.03"""

rx = re.compile(r'(\d+\.\d+(?:\.\d+)?)')

print(rx.findall(string))
# ['12.2.17', '3.04.2018', '12.2', '13.03']
```